# Non parametric anova with several colums

Tags: r, anova

```
anov_np <- kruskal.test(Sepal.Length ~Species, data=iris)
```

Hello,
Here is the syntaxe for one parameter.
I want to make a non parametric anova of several columns at the same time without loop

Comment: "non parametric anova of several columns": do you mean "sevarl anovas, each with a different column as the dependent" or "a single anova with more than one predictor".  And "without loop": would you accept `lapply` or similar?

Comment: i mean a single anova for each column. I can accept lapply or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cols <- list("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")
lapply(cols, function(x) kruskal.test(as.formula(paste(x, " ~ Species")), data=iris))
```

Comment: Check `?reformulate`.